# Firebase - getting error when importing "Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property."

Tags: firebase

It's my first time using Firebase, and I'd appreciate any help!

I had my code in one file, everything was working fine. I was trying to organize everything in separate files and folders and with the first import it breaks, giving me an "⚠  Error: Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property." The moment I bring back everything it's fine. (see below with redacted info)

So I can't bring anything out, and just import it, I tried it with several little pieces of it.
Below if you see const {signUp} = require('./handlers/users'), that causes it to break, if i comment it out (leaving the original code in) it's fine. I tried exporting just serviceAccount, and the same thing happens.

Thanks in advance!

```html
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = require('express')()

const serviceAccount = require("./admin.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "----------------------"
});

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-------------------",
    authDomain: "-----------------",
    databaseURL: "-------------------",
    projectId: "----------------",
    storageBucket: "-------------------",
    messagingSenderId: "-----------",
    appId: "----------------------------",
    measurementId: "----------------"
}
 
const db = admin.firestore()

const firebase = require('firebase')
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const {signUp} = require('./handlers/users')


//middleware to protect the code
const routeProtect = (req, res, next) => {
    let idToken
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]

    } else {
        console.error('There is no token')
        return res.status(403).json({error: 'Unauthorized'})
    }
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(decodedToken => {
            req.user = decodedToken
            console.log(decodedToken)
            return db.collection('users')
                .where('userId', '==', req.user.uid)
                .limit(1)
                .get()
        })
        .then(data => {
            req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().handle
            return next()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('There was an error with the token', err)
            return res.status(403).json(err)
        })
}

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
    db
    .collection('posts')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then(data => { 
        let posts = []
        data.forEach(doc => {
            posts.push({
                postId: doc.id,
                body: doc.data().body,
                userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
            })
        })
        return res.json(posts)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
})

app.post('/post', routeProtect, (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.body.trim() === '') {
        return res.status(400).json({body: 'Boddy cannot be empty'})
    }

    const newPost = {
        body: req.body.body,
        userHandle: req.user.handle,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
    }

    db
    .collection('posts')
    .add(newPost)
        .then(doc => {
            res.json({message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully`})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({error: 'something went wrong'})
            console.error(err)
        })
})

//email address validation helper functions
const isEmail = (email) => {
    const emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    //match() matches a string against a regular expression
    if (email.match(emailRegEx)) return true
    else return false
}
const isEmpty = (string) => {
    if (string.trim() === '') return true
    else return false
}

//signup route
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        handle: req.body.handle,
    }

    let errors = {}
    //validating the email address
    if(isEmpty(newUser.email)) {
        errors.email = 'This field cannot be empty'
    } else if (!isEmail(newUser.email)) {
        errors.email = 'You must enter a valid email address'
    }

    if(isEmpty(newUser.password)) errors.password = 'This field cannot be empty'
    if(newUser.password !== newUser.confirmPassword) errors.confirmPassword = "Passwords must be the same"
    if(isEmpty(newUser.handle)) errors.handle = 'This field cannot be empty'
    
    //need to make sure the errors object is empthy
    if(Object.keys(errors).length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors)

    //TODO validate data
    let token, userId
    db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).get()
        .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                return res.status(400).json({handle: 'this handle is already taken'})
            }else {
                return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)

            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            userId = data.user.uid
            return data.user.getIdToken()
        })
        .then(idToken => {
            token = idToken
            const userCredentials = {
                handle: newUser.handle,
                email: newUser.email,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
                userId
            }
            return db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set(userCredentials)
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(201).json({token})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            if(err.code ==='auth/email-already-in-use') {
                return res.status(400).json({email: 'Email is already in use'})
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
            }
        })

}
)

//login route
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }

    let errors = {}
 
    if(isEmpty(user.email)) errors.email = 'Cannot be empty'
    if(isEmpty(user.password)) errors.password = 'Cannot be empty'
    
    if(Object.keys(errors).length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors)

    //logging in the user
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(data => data.user.getIdToken())
        .then(token => res.json({token}))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            if(err.code === 'auth/wrong-password') return res.status(403).json({general: 'Wrong credentials, try again'})
            else return res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
        })
})

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

my admin.js contains

```html
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("./admin.js");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "-------------"
});

const db = admin.firestore()

module.exports = {admin, db}
```

Comment: what is the content of `admin.json` file?

Comment: const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("./admin.js");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "----------"
});

const db = admin.firestore()

module.exports = {admin, db}

I will add it up on the description too!

Comment: your file should contains `{
    apiKey: "-------------------",
    authDomain: "-----------------",
    databaseURL: "-------------------",
    projectId: "----------------",
    storageBucket: "-------------------",
    messagingSenderId: "-----------",
    appId: "----------------------------",
    measurementId: "----------------"
}`

Answer (score 0):

go to project setting on firebase console for app, and looking for service account tab, than at bottom clik "generate new private key", and will download new file "name-service-admin-account.json"

```js
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert('path/to/service-account-that-has-download-before.json'),
    databaseURL: "-------------"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue loading the path of your JSON secret file, you can .env variable instead, which is even easier to deploy

```js
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DB_URL,
});
```